# Using python mechanize to login on webpage with javascript md5 hashing function

Tags: javascript, python, md5, mechanize, autologin

I'm trying to use python / mechanize to login to this webpage: 
http://www.solaradata.com/cgi-bin/mainProgram.cgi

The login form uses a Javascript function that produces an MD5 hash from several field values before submitting the results for authentication. Since mechanize can't do javascript, I tried to replicate the same functionality inside of python and then submit the resulting values. However, I'm still getting "invalid user / password" errors.

Here's my current code, can anybody point me towards where I went wrong? Thanks!

```
url_login = 'http://www.solaradata.com/cgi-bin/mainProgram.cgi'

import mechanize
import md5

username  = 'superfly'  #not my real user/pass
password  = 'stickyguy' #not my real user/pass

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url_login)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.set_all_readonly(False)

session        = br['session']
br['user']     = username
br['password'] = password

m1 = md5.new()
m1.update(password + username)
br['password'] = m1.digest()

m2 = md5.new()
m2.update(password + session)
br['hash'] = m2.digest()

for form in br.forms():
  #print form

  request2 = form.click()  # mechanize.Request object
  try:
      response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2)
  except mechanize.HTTPError, response2:
      pass

  print response2.geturl()
  # headers
  for name, value in response2.info().items():
      if name != "date":
          print "%s: %s" % (name.title(), value)
  print response2.read()  # body
  response2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use m1.hexdigest() instead of m1.digest()

Comment: I tried that, but that alone does not seem to do the trick (unfortunately).

Comment: It should work :-) The HTML uses the javascript function calcMD5. I tried running that through Opera Dragonfly:

>>> calcMD5("a") 
"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"

Which is the same result you get by running:

>>> m1 = md5.new()
>>> m1.update("a")
>>> m1.hexdigest()
'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'

The results differ if there are highbit characters in the input, though. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python, but it appears the they are returning the hex value of the MD5 hash in the javascript version of the algorithm.  Does the python MD5 do the same?

You should be able to test this without going through the submission process and testing for success.  Instead, using a JavaScript developer tool such as Firebug or Chrome developer tools, calculate the result you get in-page.  Then, using the same inputs, see what you get from your program. They should match, character for character.

Comment: good catch - I did not see this. The JavaScript function called onSubmit is actually quite convoluted: function calcMD5(str) { return binl2hex(coreMD5( str2binl(str))) }. Do I read this right that it's (1) converting the string to binary, (2) calculating the MD5 hash, and (3) converting the result to base12 hex?

Comment: That's what it would seem to me.  Jump into firebug, and execute calcMD5(password.value+user.value); and calcMD5(password.value+session.value) to see what they get.  Use the same inputs in your program to compare.  Once you get them identical, you're good to go.

Comment: I looked at converting the three javascript functions in the page (str2binI, coreMD5, binI2hex) and tried to convert them to python, but they're beyond my understanding of javascript :(.

Comment: @superfly what is the length of the result that you get after your md5 computation? and what is the length of theirs? If they are different, you know for sure one of the md5's is doing something different.  Also - what is the format? does yours only contain characters 0-9 and A-F ?

Answer (score 0):

It way be overkill but if you really need to script access a javascript heavy site you can look at selenium-rc or source labs.

These tools allow you to script an actual browser the same as a user.

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)